# after popViewControllerAnimated, reload TableView issue

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, popviewcontrolleranimated

when it pops whereViewController from navigation stack, that is

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

, after this method it reloads tableview of the whereViewcontroller.
If it run exactly, it must not reload tableview.
I can't know why it run so.
It appears on ios 7 only, on iOS6 it doesn't appear.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: How do you reload your UITable? The UITable isn't reloaded automatically by itself after poping VC.

Comment: after calling popViewControllerAnimated method, although it doesn't add [tableview reloaddata], it calls numberofSeciontsInTableView, numberofRowsInSection, cellforrowatindexpath method.